# In Python/Flask, why would "from models import Result" cause a circular import error, while "from models import *" and "import models" both work?

Tags: python, flask

I'm working through the [Flask By Example tutorial](https://realpython.com/flask-by-example-part-2-postgres-sqlalchemy-and-alembic/), and I'm running into a circular import error when setting up the database through SQLAlchemy. When other people run into this problem, it seems to be because of a misplaced import statement in app.py. In my case, the error seems to depend on the way I'm importing the database models instead, which I don't understand. `import models` and `from models import *` both work, but `from models import Result` fails with the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 13, in <module>
    from models import Result
  File "/mnt/c/users/power/desktop/projects/fbe/models.py", line 1, in <module>
    from app import db
  File "/mnt/c/users/power/desktop/projects/fbe/app.py", line 13, in <module>
    from models import Result
ImportError: cannot import name 'Result' from partially initialized module 'models' (most likely due to a circular import) (/mnt/c/users/power/desktop/projects/fbe/models.py)
```

Any ideas why this might be happening? It seems like there may be some nuances to how Python does imports that I'm unaware of. It's also strange that my code is pretty much identical to the provided code, and and yet I still get an error. Could the behavior with newer versions of Python have changed? I highly doubt it, but for what it's worth I'm using 3.8.5.

My code is below. All files live in the main `app` directory.

#### app.py

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_migrate import Migrate

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_pyfile('config.py')
app.config.from_pyfile('instance/prod-config.py', silent=True)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False

db = SQLAlchemy(app)
migrate = Migrate(app, db)

### this works ###
import models

### this works too ###
# from models import *

### this fails with the above error ###
# from models import Result

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return 'Hello world!'

@app.route('/<name>')
def hello_personalized(name):
    return ('Hello ' + name)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

#### models.py

```
from app import db
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import JSON

class Result(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'results'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    url = db.Column(db.String())
    result_all = db.Column(JSON)
    result_no_stop_words = db.Column(JSON)

    def __init__(self, url, result_all, result_no_stop_words):
        self.url = url
        self.result_all = result_all
        self.result_no_stop_words = result_no_stop_words

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<id {}>'.format(self.id)
```

#### config.py

```
DEBUG = True
TESTING = True
CSRF_ENABLED = True
SECRET_KEY = 'needs-to-be-changed'
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'postgresql://username:password@localhost/fbe'
```

Answer (score 0):

Tbh, neither of those examples should work. You clearly have a circular import between those files: `from app import db` and `from models import Result`.

My guess here is that when you're using `import models` or even `from models import *`, you're importing from another package called `models` that exists on your python environment.

My solution would be to use separation of concerns and remove `db` initialization from your Flask view declarations. You can take a look on one of the many possible solutions [here](https://github.com/nnelas/crypto-api).

Comment: My understanding is that the circular import in this case should actually work though, since by the time I run `from models import Result`, the `app` variable is already defined in `app.py`. The code does run as expected (calling models.Result instead of just Result), so clearly the import works. It's more a question of why this way of importing works while the others fail.